# OpenCV Using a loop to sum a part of your image error?

Tags: c++, opencv, sum, rect, imaging

I am wanting to move through an image and take a 5x5 grid centered around each pixel in the image. I then want to sum that grid and compare it to a threshold.

```
int main()
{
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 7));

    Mat im = imread("blob.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    bool fromCenter = false;
    namedWindow("Crop frame", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Rect2d r = selectROI("Crop frame", im, fromCenter);
    im = im(r);
    erode(im, im, element);
    Mat clone = im;

    int sectionSize = 4;
    int width = im.cols - sectionSize/2;
    int height = im.rows - sectionSize/2;
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = sectionSize/2; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = sectionSize/2; j < height; j++) {

            Rect rect = Rect(i, j, sectionSize, sectionSize);
            rect -= Point(rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2);
            Mat temp = im(rect);

            for (int x = 0; x < temp.cols; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < temp.rows; y++) {
                    int pixelValue = (int)temp.at<uchar>(y, x);
                    sum += pixelValue;
                }
            }

            cout << sum << endl;

            if (sum > 3800) {
                clone.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
            }
            else {
                clone.at<uchar>(j, i) = 0;
            }

            namedWindow("erode", WINDOW_NORMAL);
            imshow("erode", clone);
            waitKey(1);
            sum = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting fluctuations in the pixel sum based on where I select my ROI in the image even when both over white space Also, my pixel sum is changing when I change the value of the clone pixel in this section of the code which I do not understand at all:

```
if (sum > 3800) {
                clone.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
            }
            else {
                clone.at<uchar>(j, i) = 0;
            }
```

Comment: Notice that when you do `Mat clone = img;`, you don't clone the `img` image. You just create a `Mat` image that points to the same memory as `img`. After this line of code you have 2 images that share the same region of memory, not data coping is done. This is why the sum changes after you modify pixel values from `clone` image. You should do `Mat clone = img.clone();` instead.

Comment: @RalucaPandaru That fixed everything! It's so ironic that I named my temp variable clone as well haha. I had no idea you had to do that for temp arrays, thank you so much!

Comment: If you are not sure how the assignment operator of a given data type works, you should read the documentation. For `Mat` take a look at https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302.